# Сохраненное значение из prompt выводится как undefined

Tags: javascript

Как сделать чтобы выводилось то, что вписывается в `prompt`? Сейчас выводит `undefined`, и не пойму почему не видит `name` и `nick`

```js
let box = document.querySelector('.box');

let user = {
  'name': prompt('Ваше имя: ', ''),
  'nick': prompt('Ваш ник: ', ''),
  'all': function(welcome, status) {
    box.innerHTML = welcome + ', ' + status + ' ' + this.name + ' ' + this.nick;
  }
}

let userAll = user.all;
userAll('Hi', 'Mr.');
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: А зачем сохранять функцию в переменную (теряя контекст при этом)? Почему не `user.all('Hi', 'Mr.');`?

Comment: я изучаю JS, прохожу определенный материал и для себя некоторые вещи просто усложняю, так проще усваивается :) Пасиб за хелпу

Answer (score 1):

Теряете контекст вызова. Добавьте `let userAll = user.all.bind(user);`